# write a program which turns a n-dimensional array or list with maximum n number of list nested to a single dimension or flat list

Tags: python, arrays, list

How to convert a list like this :

`[[1,[2,["s",2],3]],[1,2,3,4,5,6],532, "Potato", [23, [[[1,[4,[2,[]],[0],[0],  [0]]], 234, 1222], "22More"]]]`

to

`[1, 2, 's', 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 532, 'Potato', 23, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 234,    1222, '22More']`

I have tried using a for loop and then unpacking them using that but it didn't work out. Now I thought I could make variables of the element in the master list and then try unpacking them but it is not happing the way I want

Please do help

Comment: Please share what you tried, and be as precise as possible about what issues you are having with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: See i know how to flatten lists but somehow I wasn't able to create a proper recursive function

Answer (score 0):

you can use a recursive function to do that:

```
>>> list1 = [[1, [2, ['s', 2], 3]], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 532, 'Potato', [23, [[[1, [4, [2, []], [0], [0], [0]]], 234, 1222], '22More']]]
>>> def listelements(mylist):
...     rslt = []
...     for value in mylist:
...             if isinstance(value,list):
...                     rslt.extend(_listconc(value))
...             else:
...                     rslt.append(value)
...     return rslt
...
>>> listelements(list1)
[1, 2, 's', 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 532, 'Potato', 23, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 234, 1222, '22More']
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question

Comment: if this answers your question, you should check it as an answer, it could help others solve a similar problem to yours.